# Why do we need continuously increasing acceleration to go up a slope?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Now, as you go up. The value of $g$ decreases. So, as I go up a slope. It should be easier for me to travel I.e with constant acceleration or constant velocity I can travel. Why is it that if I go up with constant speed on a car, it is difficult to move up. Let us say you’re at some point on the slope after some time, you have already overcomed the friction force , $g $, normal. So, it isn’t that you need for velocity or speed to go up a slope.

Comment: Constant speed means zero acceleration, not more or less.

Comment: First of all, the value of g is constant locally. On the other hand, as you go up your potential energy increases, but that energy must come from somewhere else (remember energy is conserved because gravitational forces can be derived from a scalar potential). I think that's what you mean when tou say "it is difficult to move up".

Comment: The force of friction and the pull of gravity is continuous. It doesn't disappear the next moment just because you used enough energy to overcome it the previous moment

Comment: Can someone give like a photo where FBD is drawn , or some mathematical proof . Then , it will help me to understand .

Comment: Your scenario is no different than lifting something straight up and asking why it takes continued force to continue lifting something at a constant speed rather than zero force after you've accelerated to you your desired upward speed. Really, if you want a FBD you should come up with one yourself and then post us and ask if there is a problem with it. You'll learn a lot more and perhaps answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reduction of the force of gravity with increasing height is tiny, for the height increases caused by driving up a mountain road in a car. This is because the height of the mountain is tiny compared to the size of the earth. For practical purposes, g can be taken to be a constant in this case.

If you are going up the mountain road with constant speed, you are constantly *adding potential energy* to yourself and the car by increasing your height. That increase in potential energy is provided by the work being done by the car's engine.

This is why you cannot "coast" effortlessly up a hill.

Answer (score 0):

When driving uphill, the driving friction force from the road (generated by the powered rotating wheels) must have an “extra” vertical component.